# Claimed missing rows and columns in corresp()

Tags: r

so I'm new to R - so please forgive me if I'm making obvious mistakes through ignorance.

I'm attempting to carry out correspondence analysis. I've imported data from Excel (via CSV) using `read.csv()`. I'm then using `corresp()` from the MASS package. All is working fine.

I then go back to the CSV file (the export from Excel) and delete rows (samples I want to exclude from analysis), I then repeat the `read.csv()` and `corresp()` steps, but now I get the following error:

```
Error in corresp.matrix(as.matrix(x), ...) : empty row or column in table
In addition: Warning message:
In corresp.matrix(as.matrix(x), ...) :
  negative or non-integer entries in table
```

The 'in addition' error isn't a problem and always pops up when doing `corresp()` with non-integers. It is the first line that is the source of the problem, the claim that rows/columns are empty.

I've checked the CSV line-by-line, there are absolutely no empty cells (except A1 - as in the first CSV which was successful). In fact, the new CSV (with some rows having been removed) is near-identical to the file on which `corresp()` worked fine.

If any one has an explanation or can suggested a way to proceed it would be a massive help.

Comment: Quite possibly you've over-specified the sample size in `read.csv`  But:  Why are you doing this in Excel?  Much easier in R.  For example, to remove the 5th row from a matrix:  `my_mat <- my_mat[-5,]`

Answer (score 2):

In order to delete some of rows (or samples) from the original .csv file, you may do it easily in R and since you've already read the file, you should not get any error.

The first step is to read your original .csv file:

```
# set the header TRUE if you have any header in your .csv file.
data = read.csv(file = "", header = TRUE)
```

Now suppose you want to delete the 3rd, 5th, 10th, and 20th rows:

```
data1 = data[-(c(3, 5, 10, 20)),]
```

Then you can easily use the data.new dataframe as a new dataset.

You should note that in order to use corresp(), you should have integer and non-negative columns in your dataset. Similar to the code above, you can also select some columns of a datset. For example, in order to select only columns 3, 4, and 6 of the dataset (suppose those columns are the only non-negative integers), you can say:

```
data2 = data[,c(3, 4, 5)]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Obviously I approve of this answer, since I commented the same :-)

Comment: Hi Carl, Seems that we post at the same time...sorry about that, I didn't notice your comment :( -Best

Comment: Turned out that some of the columns added up to zero when certain rows were removed, or vice-versa. I'm very new to R and this took some frustrating work but got there in the end. Thanks for your advice guys.